# Loading Google Chrome Frame in current tab after install

Tags: google-chrome-frame

I'm prompting users of IE to install the Chrome Frame add-on. If the user is on IE and doesn't have Chrome Frame installed, they are redirected (server side) to a page with a custom message  and the install page in an IFrame:

http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?quickenable=true

After install has completed, Chrome Frame is not loaded in the current tab. Is there a way to force it to be? I've tried including redirect=True but that doesn't work because I have the page in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You make your pages work with Google Chrome Frame by adding a single tag, like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

or by adding an X-UA-Compatible HTTP response header:

```
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
```

Add the meta tag to the html file which you are loading in the frame and it should initialize the chromeframe.